# Openlayers / Openstreetmap background is vertically striped and squished

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers, openstreetmap

So the background of my openlayers implementation appears to be squished into vertical stripes.  The weird thing is that it wasn't always like this but even when I stash all my changes back to a point where I know it was working, it still is broken.  It makes me wonder if perhaps something has changed about the way the tile assets are being delivered.  I have tried switching between using osm and wms layers with no change, any help would be appreciated.

Here is the pertinent code:

```
initMap: function() {
  var view = this;
  var map = this.map = new OpenLayers.Map();
  map.render(this.$map[0]);

  var wmsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
    "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", {layers: 'basic'});

  var osmLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();

  this.layers = {
    point: new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Point Layer"),
    line: new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Line Layer"),
    polygon: new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Polygon Layer")
  };

  this.setValue(this.value);

  map.addLayers([this.layers.point, this.layers.line, this.layers.polygon, osmLayer]);

  drawControls = {
    point: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(this.layers.point,
      OpenLayers.Handler.Point),
    line: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(this.layers.line,
      OpenLayers.Handler.Path),
    polygon: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(this.layers.polygon,
      OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon)
  };

  this.layers[this.layerType].events.on({'sketchcomplete': function(feature) {

    if (!view.multiple) {
      // deactivate polygon layer once a polygon has been added
      drawControls[view.layerType].deactivate();
    }

  }});

  for(var key in drawControls) {
    map.addControl(drawControls[key]);
  }

  if (this.layers[this.layerType].features.length) {
    var bounds = this.layers[this.layerType].getDataExtent();
    var zoom = this.layers[this.layerType].getZoomForExtent(bounds);
    var lon = (bounds.top - bounds.bottom) / 2;
    var lat = (bounds.right - bounds.left) / 2;
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon,lat), 3);
    map.zoomToExtent(bounds);

    if (view.multiple) {
      drawControls[view.layerType].activate();
    }

  } else {
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-11174482.03751,4861394.9982606), 4);
    drawControls[view.layerType].activate();
  }

  this.$('.clear').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    view.layers[view.layerType].destroyFeatures();
    drawControls[view.layerType].activate();
  });
},
```

Here is the output:

[image: here is the output]

Answer (score 19):

So I found the problem.  Twitter bootstrap has a line in its reset file that sets:

```
img { max-width: 100% }
```

This was squishing the images.  You can fix it by doing:

```
img { max-width: none; }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
I was having the same problem, are you using bootstrap of twitter? 

I found out there was a selector for img elements that was affecting the map. I had the next selector into the bootstrap.css"

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

I don't know whay the parameter max-width: 100%; makes the vertical stripes in my case. I remove the propertie max-width: 100% and now is working.
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting `img { max-width: 100% }` to `img { max-width:none; }` does resolve the problem.

**However** this will have an unintended effect on images throughout your website. I am also using Bootstrap Twitter's carousel component for images and when I made the above changed the images did not fit in the carousel. Therefore I changed it so that it only targets the images in the OpenLayers / OpenStreetMap div.

```
div#outlet_map img { max-width:none; }
```